# Flask-login doesn't need re-login after system reboot

Tags: flask, flask-login

I have reference by [flask-login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) document and test it, I have a question: After the system restarts, why not user is asked for a new login?

Comment: Because the user's cookie is stored in their client, not in memory on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accurately, the secret key was used to the session. If you had reboot or restart application, and regenerated the secret key, all the existing sessions would be invalidated.